# adding a hyperlink to a workitem (not a link to another workitem)

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

How can I go about adding a hyperlink (not a link to another workitem) to a workitem in TFS (using the API)?

Comment: The TFS that I am using is the one that comes with VS 2010. Beyond that, I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Hyperlink hl = new Hyperlink("http://microsoft.com");
hl.Comment = "Microsoft";

workItem.Links.Add(hl);
```

[Reference](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/10/06/more-about-creating-work-item-using-tfs-api.aspx)